# How to add a div to a Dialog?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have create a dijit/form/Button and add it to my page. When I pressed the button, there should be for example a dataGrid with data and other buttons for more functions. I created a new form and add a dropdown Menu and some other buttons. Now I would like to add to this form a dataGrid or a second form for the dataGrid. How is this possible? Here is the code for example:

```
var form = new Form({ 
    style: 'height: 100px'
});

new DropDownButton({
    dropDown: menu,
    label: "layers"
}).placeAt(form.containerNode);

var menu = new DropDownMenu({ style: "display: none" });

var menuItem1 = new MenuItem({
    label: "test",
    onClick: function () { alert("test"); }
});

menu.addChild(menuItem1);

new Button({
    label: "OK"
}).placeAt(form.containerNode);

new Button({
    label: "Cancel"
}).placeAt(form.containerNode);

dialog = new Dialog ({
    content: form,
    title: 'Title',
});

form.startup();
```

When I add form2 then is only show the first one, but not form and form2. How can I add a second form for the dataGrid or the dataGrid to the first form with buttons.
Maybe I should add a new div to the DOM. But how can I add a new div to the DOM into the button?

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: I am using the .NET

Comment: How did you add a `form2` and what do you mean with "only show the first one, but not `form` and `form2`"? Isn't `form` the first one?

Comment: Quite a confusing question.  I would say that you do not need a Form (I presume you mean `dijit/form/Form`?) to contain widgets or other content.  `Form` is basically a `<form>` element that is useful when you will `POST` content to your backend.  A `dijit/Dialog` creates DOM nodes that include a `containerNode` div, in which your `content` will be placed, you can add anything you want in there, but it must all be children of that single div, e.g. append your two forms to it as child nodes.  Your `DropDownMenu` seems irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the form2 as follow:

```
var form = new Form({ 
style: 'height: 100px'
});

var form2 = new Form({
style: 'height: 100px'
});

var layout = [
{name: 'ID'},
{name: 'test'}
];

var grid = new DataGrid({
structure: layout
}).placeAt(form2.containerNode);

new DropDownButton({
dropDown: menu,
label: "layers"
}).placeAt(form.containerNode);

var menu = new DropDownMenu({ style: "display: none" });

var menuItem1 = new MenuItem({
label: "test",
onClick: function () { alert("test"); }
});

menu.addChild(menuItem1);

new Button({
label: "OK"
}).placeAt(form.containerNode);

new Button({
label: "Cancel"
}).placeAt(form.containerNode);

dialog = new Dialog ({
content: form,
title: 'Title',
});

form.startup();
form2.startup();
```

And now I'm not sure how to add the form2 to the content of the dialog.

Comment: This would be better added as an Edit on the original question, not an Answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest you would be better off structuring your code as custom widgets, but it looks like your on an earlier part of the learning curve.  Here's a little example of adding content to an existing Dialog.

Your details of `DataGrid` (you know this is pretty much deprecated by `dgrid` http://dgrid.io, right?) and `DropDownMenu`s are not relevant to your original question, if I understand it correctly.

```js
require([
  'dijit/Dialog',
  'dijit/form/Form',
  'dijit/form/Button'
], function (Dialog, Form, Button) {
  
  document.body.className = 'claro';
  
  var form = new Form();
  
  var b1 = new Button({
    label: 'Click me'
  });
  
  b1.placeAt(form.domNode);
  
  b1.on('click', function () {
  
    // Now create some new content for the Dialog.
    // We have closure scope visibility of the dialog reference
    var form2 = new Form();
    var b2 = new Button({
      label: 'I am a second button (I do nothing)'
    });
    
    // Append the new content as children of the dialog's content
    dialog.containerNode.appendChild(b2.domNode);
  });
  
  var dialog = new Dialog({
    title: 'A dialog',
    content: form
  });
  dialog.startup();
  dialog.show();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
```